# Hyper-V Nextcloud server crashes - task jbd2 blocked for more than 120 seconds

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v, ubuntu-16.04, nextcloud

I hope this is the right place for my question.
I have recently set up a ubuntu 16 LTS server running in a hyper-v VM on my windows 2012R2 server. That ubuntu server is running nextcloud and everything needed for that (mainly php 7, nginx, mariadb, lets encrypt).
It worked fine for some weeks but recently it started to crash every few days.
I can't access the nextcloud instance and trying to ssh into the vm doesn't work either.
When I connect to the machine via Hyper-V I get to see these errors:
mainly
`blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0`
and `task xyz/... blocked for more than 120 seconds.`

[Server error Messag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hb5xZ.png)

Any idea what causes this error or how to fix it? I don't know why it should be so slow. Hyper-V itself is running from the system SSD and the VM data is stored on a normal HDD that isn't really used that much either.

PS After restarting the server runs without problems (for some time at least)

PPS /var/log/syslog shows some error about the floppy drive too. Why is the system trying to access that?

```
Feb 10 14:43:35 NextCloudServer kernel: [173964.658498] floppy0: unexpected interrupt
Feb 10 14:43:35 NextCloudServer kernel: [173964.658585] floppy0: sensei repl[0]=80
Feb 10 14:43:35 NextCloudServer kernel: [173964.658614] floppy0: seek failed
Feb 10 14:43:35 NextCloudServer kernel: [173964.696404] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
Feb 10 14:43:35 NextCloudServer kernel: [173964.696429] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
Feb 10 14:43:56 NextCloudServer kernel: [173985.224253] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
Feb 10 14:43:56 NextCloudServer kernel: [173985.224286] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
Feb 10 14:44:18 NextCloudServer kernel: [174007.240251] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
Feb 10 14:44:18 NextCloudServer kernel: [174007.240284] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
Feb 10 14:44:37 NextCloudServer kernel: [174026.972147] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
Feb 10 14:44:37 NextCloudServer kernel: [174026.972171] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
```

I couldn't find any other errors in there

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved this (at least for now) by simply removing the floppy drive like described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53513/linux-disable-dev-fd0-floppy).